# Guzzle http not working with proxy and verify

Tags: php, http, https, proxy, guzzle

I am facing issue using 'verify' setting to CA file and setting up proxy with http & https options.

```
$result = $client->request ( 'POST', /, [
'verify' => 'C:\xampp\cacert.pem',
'proxy' => [
'http' => '127.0.0.1:8080', // Use this proxy with "http"
'https' => '127.0.0.1:8080' // Use this proxy with "https"
]);
```

Getting error as "cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)"

I am using burpsuite as proxy listener and using cacert.pem latest file downloaded from curl site.

I tried using CA cert file exporting from burpsuite as well but also did not work.

Please let me know, any possible solution to this.

Comment: set this: `new GuzzleClient(['verify' => false ]);` or get non self signed certificate...

Comment: from where I will get this non self signed certificate?

Comment: https://letsencrypt.org/